# Improving Speed of Binomial and Multinomial Random Draws

Tags: numerics, random

A number of users have discussed the speed of Random number generation in Mathematica.

The Binomial and Multinomial random number generators in Mathematica are fast if multiple draws are needed for the same distribution parameters. For example, generating 500000 draws from the Binomial distribution is very quick

```
In[30]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[100, 0.6], 500000];]

Out[30]= {0.017365, Null}
```

However, the speed is slow compared to that in R and Julia when the parameters change across draws, as may be required when performing certain Monte Carlo simulations.

For example, if we have a vector nvec that contains the number of trials for each draw and a vector pvec that contains the corresponding probabilities of success.

```
nvec = RandomInteger[{5, 125}, 500000];

pvec = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 500000];
```

Then we have

```
In[28]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 Mean[Table[
    RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[nvec[[i]], pvec[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
     Length@nvec}]] // N
 ]

Out[28]= {36.2144, 32.5283}
```

This hit in speed most probably stems from how these are implemented internally in Mathematica.

Are there alternate methods that are fast for the case when the parameter distribution changes across the draws?

Comment: I thought using `ParameterMixtureDistribution` might help.  It didn't.  `dist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[n, p], {n \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{5, 125}], p \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]` is just as slow.

Answer (score 6):

Fast random number generators for the Binomial are described in

Kachitvichyanukul, V.; Schmeiser, B.W. ["Binomial random variate generation."](https://doi.org/10.1145/42372.42381) Comm.ACM 31 (1988), no .2, 216 - 222.

A Mathematica implementation based on the above paper involves the following three functions.

When the number of trials is small, the Geometric method from

Devroye. L. "[Generating the maximum of independent identically distributed random variables](https://doi.org/10.1016/0898-1221(80)90039-5)." Computers and Mathematics with Applications 6, 1960, 305-315.  can be used.

```
ablRanBinGeom = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {p, _Real}}, 
   Module[
        {y = 0, x = 0, comp = 0, er, v, scale = 0.0},
        If[p >= 1.0, Return[n]];
        If[p <= 0.5, comp = 0; scale = -1.0/Internal`Log1p[-p], comp = 1;
      scale = -1.0/Log[p]];
        While[True, 
            er = -Log[RandomReal[]];
            v = er*scale;
            If[v > n, Break[]];
            y = y + Ceiling[v];
            If[y > n, Break[]];
            x = x + 1;
        ];
        If[comp == 1, n - x, x]
        ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];
```

For larger n, we can use

```
    ablRanBinBtpe = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {p, _Real}},
   Module[
        {comp = 0, r, q, nrq, fM, M, Mi, p1, xM, xL, xR, c, a, lamL, 
     lamR, p2, p3, p4,
        y, u, v, x, k, S, F, t, A, x1, f1, z, w, rho},

        If[p >= 1.0, Return[n]];

        If[p <= 0.5, 
            comp = 0; r = p; q = 1.0 - p, 
            comp = 1; r = 1.0 - p; q = p
        ];

        nrq = n*r*q;
        fM = (n + 1)*r;
        M = Floor[fM];
        Mi = Floor[M];
        p1 = Floor[2.195*Sqrt[nrq] - 4.6*q] + 0.5;
        xM = M + 0.5;
        xL = xM - p1;
        xR = xM + p1;
        c = 0.134 + 20.5/(15.3 + M);
        a = (fM - xL)/(fM - xL*r);
        lamL = a*(1.0 + 0.5*a);
        a = (xR - fM)/(xR*q);
        lamR = a*(1.0 + 0.5*a);
        p2 = p1*(1.0 + 2.0*c);
        p3 = p2 + c/lamL;
        p4 = p3 + c/lamR;

        y = 0;

        While[True, (* Step 1 *)

            u = p4*RandomReal[];
            v = RandomReal[];
            Which[
                u <=  p1, 
                y = Floor[xM - p1*v + u];
                Break[],

                u <= p2, (* Step 2 *)
                x = xL + (u - p1)/c;
                v = v*c + 1.0 - Abs[M - x + 0.5]/p1;
                If[v > 1, Continue[]];
                y = Floor[x],

                u <= p3 ,(* Step 3 *)
                y = Floor[xL + Log[v]/lamL];
                If[y < 0, Continue[]];
                v = v*(u - p2)*lamL,

                True, (* Step 4 *)

                y = Floor[xR - Log[v]/lamR];
                If[y > n, Continue[]];
                v = v*(u - p3)*lamR
            ];
            A = Log[v]; 
     If[A > (LogGamma[Mi + 1] + LogGamma[n - Mi + 1] + 
         LogGamma[y + 1] + LogGamma[n - y + 1] + (y - Mi)*Log[r/q]), 
      Continue[]
      ];
     Break[];
     ];
        If[comp == 1, n - y, y]
    ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];
```

We can automatically choose the appropriate method using the function

```
ablRanBinomial = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {p, _Real}},
   Module[
        {q = 1.0 - p},
        If[n*Min[p, q] > 20, ablRanBinBtpe[n, p], ablRanBinGeom[n, p]]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];
```

Here is the performance improvement.

```
In[32]:= AbsoluteTiming[
  Mean@Table[
    ablRanBinomial[nvec[[i]], pvec[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@nvec}]] // N

Out[32]= {0.413019, 32.5307}
```

This can be further improved using the Listability attribute for the function.

```
In[33]:= AbsoluteTiming[Mean@ablRanBinomial[nvec, pvec] // N]

Out[33]= {0.156881, 32.5337}
```

Once we have the function for Binomial draws, this can be used in a function for fast generation of multinomial draws with n being the number of trails and p being a vector of probabilities that sum to 1.

```
ablRanMultinomial=Compile[{{n, _Integer},{p, _Real, 1}},
Module[
    {k=Length[p], rp,i, km1,cn,pi,xi,x},
    rp=1.0;cn=n;
    i=0;
    km1=k-1;
    x=Table[0, {k}];
    While[i<km1 && cn >0,
        i+=1;
        pi=p[[i]];
        If[pi < rp,
            xi=ablRanBinomial[cn, pi/rp];
            x[[i]]=xi;
            cn-=xi;
            rp-=pi;,
            x[[i]]=cn;
            cn=0
        ];
    ];
    If[i==km1, x[[k]]=cn,
        Do[x[[j]]=0,{j,i+1, k}]
    ];
    x
],
CompilationTarget->"C", 
CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}
];
```

This can be used as follows:

```
In[36]:= ablRanMultinomial[20, {0.5, 0.3, 0.2}]

Out[36]= {12, 7, 1}
```

Comment: Performance improvement looks impressive - it would be helpful though to know if there was any quality impediment in adopting the above.