# Multinomial Distribution Sampler Not Working

Tags: random

I am trying to sample from a multinomial distribution many times but with a different multinomial distribution each time. The straightforward

```
RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[1,{p1, p2, ..., pN}]]
```

is too slow for my application. I wrote my own sampler where I use `Accumulate` on the distribution and then use `RandomReal[]` to choose one possible outcome.

```
S = 300;
dis = Accumulate@Table[1/S, {k, 1, S}];
GetRand[dist_] := FirstPosition[dist, SelectFirst[dist, # >= RandomReal[] &]][[1]];
test = Table[GetRand[dis], {k, 1, 100000}];
Histogram[test, S, "PDF"]
```

Because `dis` is uniform, my expectation is that the histogram should be mostly uniform. Instead I get a histogram which is clearly not uniform. I've found that I get the correct result if I separately generate a table of all the random reals and then use them to sample from the multinomial distribution.

[image]

Why does this code not give a uniform histogram? Also, why does it appear to give a distribution from the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Why do you think "`dis` is uniform"?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the solution that I posted sometime ago. You will need a C compiler on your machine. Also note that the function does not check to ensure that the inputs for consistency with the requirements of a distribution.

[Improving Speed of Multinomial Draws](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/196889/improving-speed-of-binomial-and-multinomial-random-draws?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really wanting to sample from a multinomial, then go with @Asim 's answer.

But the example you give isn't really a multinomial as the result from `GetRand` (after using the correction below) is just the position of the success category with a sample size of one.

I think the issue is that `RandomReal[]` is called internally for each element in `dist` rather than being a single call to `RandomReal[]`.  Therefore, the element selected never gets much past 60 as there are multiple chances to get a low number.  (I would bet that's by design rather than considered a bug.)  The fix might be the following:

```
S = 300;
dis = Accumulate@Table[1/S, {k, 1, S}];
GetRand[dist_] := Module[{r},
   r = RandomReal[];
   FirstPosition[dist, SelectFirst[dist, # >= r &]][[1]]];
test = Table[GetRand[dis], {k, 1, 100000}];
Histogram[test, S, "PDF"]
```

[image: Histogram for test]

If you only need the position of what is selected from a sample of size 1, then `RandomChoice` should be considered:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
AbsoluteTiming[test = Table[GetRand[dis], {k, 1, 100000}];]
(* {8.72437, Null} *) 
SeedRandom[12345];
AbsoluteTiming[RandomChoice[Range[300], 100000];]
(* {0.0012076, Null} *)
```